# Swift UI animated closure

Tags: swiftui

If I have a SwiftUI view declaration like:

```
ProfileView(userData, onDoneEdit: {
withAnimation {
        isEditingViewPresented.toggle()
    }
...
}, onCancel: { ... })
```

does anyone know if it can be implemented a custom annotation that let me have:

```
ProfileView(userData, onDoneEdit: { @withAnimation
    isEditingViewPresented.toggle()
    ...
    }, onCancel: { ... })
```

This question is more for learning purpose as I'm experimenting with SwiftUI.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible. However, you could wrap your `onDoneEdit` using `withAnimation` directly where you're calling it.